# Google Sheets - IF with ISBLANK

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, localization

I am working in google sheets and I would like to ask you one thing.
I want to check if cell is blank and if it is it should return 0, if it is not it should calculate the formula, which I have used befere.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh4dc.png (can not post image...)
But I am still getting this #ERROR! which says error when analyzing formula. I have tried it in Microsoft Excel and exact formula works...

Did somebody already solved this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(J15); 0; J15-J14)
```

Comment: Hi, yes it worked thanks a lot 